# Pip packages not importing

Tags: python-3.x, macos, unix, pip

So I am unable to use the package PyMySQL from pip.
I've tried installing it with pip, pip3, and easy install.
I've tried running the file in python2 and python3.
I've tried using 
`python -m pip install ...`

I'm on mac.
My ~/.bash_profile has the following

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/taylorcochran/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH="/usr/local/cellar/openvpn:$Path"
export PATH="/Users/taylorcochran/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:$PATH"
```

I've looked at similar problem across StackOverflow but none of the suggested solutions produce any results.

Additionally, when I try to add `# PATH="/usr/local/lib"`
 to my path it breaks the built in commands like `ls` and `cd`

Edit:

I'm running the script using `python3 Test.py` which simply contains the line `import PyMySQL`
Which outputs: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMySQL'`

Tried:
`pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framewor k/Versions/3.6" PyMySQL`

Outputs: 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options. cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options) Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

And still doesn't let my import the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Python 3.6 in the `PYTHONPATH` so you should go with pip3. Try to use the following command:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name
```

where `$PREFIX_PATH` in your case should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6`

When you use Python located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` the module library should be available.

Comment: `pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framewor
k/Versions/3.6" PyMySQL `

Outputs:

 `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py:194: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-options / --global-options / --install-options.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`        And still doesn't let my import the module

Comment: @user8642594 Could you post a command you execute to start python? Do you run Python located in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framewor k/Versions/3.6`? How do you import the library and what error message do you see?

Comment: `python3 Test.py` which only contains the line `import PyMySQL`                   Returns: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMySQL'`

Comment: It's `import pymysql` not `import PyMySQL` as I can see on my console and on the project page - [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)

Comment: That's officially the dummest mistake in my coding career. Thanks for being so patient.